# I have a common complex scenario of creating groups at run time on multiple columns in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Pattern is like only master being changed in col1 but all the values are same in col2. like

[[image]

Input Table

```
id  Col1    Col2    ColC
1   A1      A2      1
2   A1      A3      1
3   A1      A1      1
4   A2      A2      2
5   A2      A1      2
6   A2      A3      2
7   A3      A1      3
8   A3      A2      3
9   A3      A3      3
10  B1      B1      4
11  B1      B2      4
12  B1      B3      4
13  B2      B1      5
14  B2      B2      5
15  B2      B3      5
16  B3      B1      6
17  B3      B2      6
18  B3      B3      6
```

Output Result Should Be Like this

```
id  Col1    Col2    ColC    Group
1   A1      A2      1       G1
2   A1      A3      1       G1
3   A1      A1      1       G1
4   A2      A2      2       G1
5   A2      A1      2       G1
6   A2      A3      2       G1
7   A3      A1      3       G1
8   A3      A2      3       G1
9   A3      A3      3       G1
10  B1      B1      4       G2
11  B1      B2      4       G2
12  B1      B3      4       G2
13  B2      B1      5       G2
14  B2      B2      5       G2
15  B2      B3      5       G2
16  B3      B1      6       G2
17  B3      B2      6       G2
18  B3      B3      6       G2
```

I use Update statement in a loop to resolve the issue but this is not good enough below are the insert and update statement for the table.

```
Create Table #attachment (id int identity,effective_date int, Col1 int, Aid int, SCID int, Col3 int,
 termination_date int, Col2 int,Groups int)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42005',100073,71,3,21885,'42190',100073)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42005',100073,71,3,21885,'42190',100539)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42005',100073,71,3,21885,'42190',100561)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42005',100073,71,3,21885,'42190',103532)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42005',100073,71,3,21885,'42190',105078)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42219',103532,71,3,41483,'42262',100073)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42219',103532,71,3,41483,'42262',100539)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42219',103532,71,3,41483,'42262',100561)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42219',103532,71,3,41483,'42262',103532)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42219',103532,71,3,41483,'42262',105078)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42280',100561,71,3,41484,'42311',100073)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42280',100561,71,3,41484,'42311',100539)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42280',100561,71,3,41484,'42311',100561)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42280',100561,71,3,41484,'42311',103532)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42280',100561,71,3,41484,'42311',105078)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42341',103532,71,3,41485,'42581',100073)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42341',103532,71,3,41485,'42581',100539)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42341',103532,71,3,41485,'42581',100561)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42341',103532,71,3,41485,'42581',103532)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('42341',103532,71,3,41485,'42581',105078)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('423',103,71,3,41485,'42581',105)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('423',103,71,3,41485,'42581',103)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('423',105,71,3,41485,'42581',105)
    Insert into #attachment (effective_date, Col1, Aid, SCID, Col3, termination_date, Col2)values('423',105,71,3,41485,'42581',103)
```

here is the update statement

```
Declare @id int = 1, @Col1 int, @Col3 int,@maxid int = 24,@Groups int,@maxgropid int 
while @id <= @maxid
begin

    select @maxgropid = MAx(Groups) from  #attachment 

    select @Col1 = Col1 ,@Col3 =Col3,@Groups = Groups  from #attachment where id = @id 
    select @id,@maxgropid,@Col1
    IF @Groups is null 
    Begin 
    update #attachment set Groups = isnull(@maxgropid,0)+1
    where @Col1 In (
    select Distinct Col1 from #attachment where Col2 In (select Col2 from 
    #attachment where Col1 = @Col1)) and Col2 in (select Col2 from 
    #attachment where Col1 = @Col1)
    --and id = @id 
    end 
    set @id = @id+1


end
```

How to get group column result in select statement instead of update one.

---

Comment: Your output is not very clear. Please add some explanations

Comment: We are not a code writing service. What have you tried? What do you actually need? This is just a data dump, which won't get you an answer.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I am not asking you to write the code right this is a community and i have every right to ask the question when i puzzled.

Comment: I agree with HoneyBadger. This is a bad question. Please read [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: "help me to write a query" sounds very much like "write code for me". Anyway, if you want help, at least give us enough information. It is not at all clear what your actual question or problem is.

Comment: @Gurv here you see a common scenario column2 values like A1,A2,A3 are repeating in Group A1,A2 and A3 same as B1 ,B2 and B3. but there are only 2 Groups G1 and G2 .

Comment: @Chanukya you did good effort but this need to be done by dynamical not  hard coded .

Comment: @ArunGairola Why don't you edit your question to provide more detail of your requirements? You got an answer which produces your expected result. Apparently this is not good enough; how are we to know what you want if you don't tell us?

Comment: i have provided you input and output can you write the query to get Groups column dynamicaly based on input data ?

Comment: I will put bounty on this question the question was correct few of community member are not able to understand the question might be after bounty they know what i want specially @HoneyBadger you people create a mess of this type of community .so please dont do this. this is not your home ...

Comment: @ArunGairola I was just asking for clarification so we (I and everybody else at SO) could help you better, why so insulted? What mess did I make? The edit on your question helped to elucidate your actual requirements, thanks for that, hope you get a good answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using update statement .

```
Declare @id int = 1, @Col1 int, @Col3 int,@maxid int = 24,@Groups int,@maxgropid int 
    while @id <= @maxid
    begin

        select @maxgropid = MAx(Groups) from  #attachment 

        select @Col1 = Col1 ,@Col3 =Col3,@Groups = Groups  from #attachment where id = @id 
        select @id,@maxgropid,@Col1
        IF @Groups is null 
        Begin 
        update #attachment set Groups = isnull(@maxgropid,0)+1
        where @Col1 In (
        select Distinct Col1 from #attachment where Col2 In (select Col2 from 
        #attachment where Col1 = @Col1)) and Col2 in (select Col2 from 
        #attachment where Col1 = @Col1)
        --and id = @id 
        end 
        set @id = @id+1


    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
    SELECT *,'G'+LTRIM(DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY LEFT(t.Col1,1))) 
    FROM (values
       (1, 'A1', 'A2', 1),
        (2, 'A1', 'A3', 1),
        (3, 'A1', 'A1', 1),
        (4, 'A2', 'A2', 2),
        (5, 'A2', 'A1', 2),
        (6, 'A2', 'A3', 2),
        (7, 'A3', 'A1', 3),
        (8, 'A3', 'A2', 3),
        (9, 'A3', 'A3', 3),
        (10, 'B1', 'B1', 4),
        (11, 'B1', 'B2', 4),
        (12, 'B1', 'B3', 4),
        (13, 'B2', 'B1', 5),
        (14, 'B2', 'B2', 5),
        (15, 'B2', 'B3', 5),
        (16, 'B3', 'B1', 6),
        (17, 'B3', 'B2', 6),
        (18, 'B3', 'B3', 6)
        ) t(ID,Col1,Col2,Colc)
```

```
ID          Col1 Col2 Colc        
----------- ---- ---- ----------- -------------------------
1           A1   A2   1           G1
2           A1   A3   1           G1
3           A1   A1   1           G1
4           A2   A2   2           G1
5           A2   A1   2           G1
6           A2   A3   2           G1
7           A3   A1   3           G1
8           A3   A2   3           G1
9           A3   A3   3           G1
10          B1   B1   4           G2
11          B1   B2   4           G2
12          B1   B3   4           G2
13          B2   B1   5           G2
14          B2   B2   5           G2
15          B2   B3   5           G2
16          B3   B1   6           G2
17          B3   B2   6           G2
18          B3   B3   6           G2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([id] int, [Col1] varchar(2), [Col2] varchar(2), [ColC] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([id], [Col1], [Col2], [ColC])
VALUES
    (1, 'A1', 'A2', 1),
    (2, 'A1', 'A3', 1),
    (3, 'A1', 'A1', 1),
    (4, 'A2', 'A2', 2),
    (5, 'A2', 'A1', 2),
    (6, 'A2', 'A3', 2),
    (7, 'A3', 'A1', 3),
    (8, 'A3', 'A2', 3),
    (9, 'A3', 'A3', 3),
    (10, 'B1', 'B1', 4),
    (11, 'B1', 'B2', 4),
    (12, 'B1', 'B3', 4),
    (13, 'B2', 'B1', 5),
    (14, 'B2', 'B2', 5),
    (15, 'B2', 'B3', 5),
    (16, 'B3', 'B1', 6),
    (17, 'B3', 'B2', 6),
    (18, 'B3', 'B3', 6)
;

;with cte as 
(
select  * ,left(col1,1) new_column from #Table1
)
select id, [Col1], [Col2], [ColC], case when new_column= 'A' then 'G1' else 'G2' end as n from cte


id  Col1    Col2    ColC    n
1   A1  A2  1   G1
2   A1  A3  1   G1
3   A1  A1  1   G1
4   A2  A2  2   G1
5   A2  A1  2   G1
6   A2  A3  2   G1
7   A3  A1  3   G1
8   A3  A2  3   G1
9   A3  A3  3   G1
10  B1  B1  4   G2
11  B1  B2  4   G2
12  B1  B3  4   G2
13  B2  B1  5   G2
14  B2  B2  5   G2
15  B2  B3  5   G2
16  B3  B1  6   G2
17  B3  B2  6   G2
18  B3  B3  6   G2
```

or

```
  SELECT *,'G'+LTRIM(DENSE_RANK()OVER(ORDER BY LEFT(Col1,1)))  from #table1
```